# Any good open source tools for doing WSP installations for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: deployment, installation

I've heard that [SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/) is a good one, but it only works for 2007 and the 2010 version only appears to be in the planning phase.

Does anyone know of any existing tools out there that work for 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't Powershell be adequate?

Comment: I'd like something a little more user friendly.  I won't be the person doing the installs.

Comment: PowerShell is the way to go, hands down, ifyou want a repeatable install. However you need to describe exactly what permissions need to be present for the user executing the script (such as shell admin, farm admin, local admin)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Marc - it should be done with PowerShell.

You might think it's not user friendly but if you write the script so it's a single command it can't be any easier for the admins to install it. The script way also allows the IT-pros to inspect what you're actually trying to do which MSI's or EXE's don't.

I do recommend you to take a look at Gary "PowerShell" Lapointes solution deployment script: http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/04/deploying-sharepoint-2010-solution-package-using-powershell-revisited

Comment: Alright, well maybe I'll revisit that then.